# How do I send a Android data packet to server via socket?

Tags: android, sockets, client

How do I send a Android data packet to socket server? My current code is causing the app to quit. Android 4.2.2 on a Samsung Galaxy GT-P5210. I can successfully connect to the remote device with WiFiP2pManager.

```
                    String wr_data = ">04" + (char) 0x0D + (char) 0x0A;     // GAA 04Jan2018
                    Socket client = null;
                    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Start socket connection");
                    toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Start socket connection", duration);
                    toast.show();
                    try {

                        InetAddress cc3200Address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.146");

                        client = new Socket(cc3200Address, PORT);

                        OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
```

//                            InputStream is = client.getInputStream();                //GAA 04Jan2018

```
                            len = wr_data.length();
                            os.write(wr_data.getBytes(), 0, len);

                        os.close();
```

//                          inputStream.close();

```
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                        if (client != null) {
                            if (client.isConnected()) {
                                try {
                                    client.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // Give up
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Yes your app will not quit but crash with this code. Very obvious. And you can find the exception in the logcat. Please have a look.

Comment: `String wr_data = ">04" + (char) 0x0D + (char) 0x0A;`. You mean: `String wr_data = ">04\r\n"; `.

Comment: Change InetAddress cc3200Address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.146"); to igetByAddress(ipaddr)

Comment: Is there anything to wanted to tell us? Or ask? Why this comment?

Comment: Just wanted to make he correction to use find by address as opposed to find by name.

Comment: I'm hoping that I don't have to run a background thread to send a string to a server. Not a lot of experience with this so if you could point me to a tutorial that would be great.

Comment: Stopped the crash with UnknownHostException

Comment: Yes you have to put all internet code in a thread or asynctask. And you cannot use a Toast() there. Thats why i said your code would crash and could not work.